# Halting problem reduction, what am i doing wrong

Tags: computer-science, computability, turing-machines

I have the following problem.
Prove that $L_1=\{\langle M\rangle| \exists w \in \Sigma^*: M(w)\downarrow\}$  is undecidable (where $M(w) \downarrow$ means M halts on input w).

I have come up with this reduction ($\langle M\rangle w\longmapsto \langle M'\rangle$) wich i know is wrong but i can't figure out why.

M' on input y:

```
deletes y from the tape
writes w on the tape
executes M on w
```

i tried to show the correctness as follow:
$$\langle M\rangle w \in L_{halt} \Rightarrow M(w) \downarrow \Rightarrow M'(y) \downarrow \Rightarrow \langle M'\rangle\in L_1$$

$$\langle M\rangle w \notin L_{halt} \Rightarrow M(w) \uparrow \Rightarrow M'(y) \uparrow \Rightarrow \langle M'\rangle \notin L_1$$

Now, I know that the proof i wrote is wrong since it's the proof used to demostrate that $L_{\Sigma^*}=\{\langle M\rangle|\forall w \in \Sigma^*, M(w) \downarrow\}$ is undecidable,but i don't know where i am wrong.

Comment: I don't think this is incorrect. This reduction just happens to solve both problems because being in $L_{\Sigma^*}$ implies being in $L_1$.

Comment: Ok i understand, can i also prove it by contradiction? if i suppose that this problem is decidable then for any input i can decide weather the input is accepted or rejected. Where accepted means that the TM enters a halting state. This leads to halting problem being decidable. Is this correct?

Comment: @giggiox this is not correct as is, because you solve not halting problem (if TM stops on given input), but some other (if there is an input such that TM stops on it).

Answer (score 1):

This is correct. Your reduction gives machine that behaves equally on any input, and for such machines membership in $L_1$ and $L_{\Sigma^*}$ is equal.

More precisely, your reduction maps $L_{halt}$ to machines that halts on every input (let it be $L'$) and $\overline{L_{halt}}$ to machines that doesn't halt at any input (let it be $L''$).

As $L' \subseteq L_1 \cap L_{\Sigma^*}$ and $L'' \subseteq \overline{L_1} \cap \overline{L_{\Sigma^*}}$, this is reduction both to $L_1$ and $L_{\Sigma^*}$.

Comment: thanks. I want now to understand now what's the thought process behind the solution i was given. "M' on any input y checks if y=w, if this is true executes M on w else M' enters in a loop". Is this solution more "precise"? i don't understand the thought process behind this.

Comment: The thought process was likely something like: for any TM, we can check, if there is an input such that it stops on it. But we are given a machine and input, and want to check if the machine stops on this exact input. How to do it? By making machine that stops on any input iff our machine stops on our input. No additional checks required.

Comment: I understand, just another related question, if i have this language: $L_2=\{⟨M⟩| 1101 \in L(M) \}$ and i define the reduction as the tm M' on input y: if y=1101 then execute M(w) else loop. Is this reduction correct? I know i can solve this with rice theorem, i just want to understand.